# Webpack multiple files entry bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack, babel-polyfill

Will webpack produce different results given a configuration like so:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    ...
    entry: {
        main: ['./index.js'],
    }
}


// index.js
import 'babel-polyfill'
...
```

vs.

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    ...
    entry: {
        main: ['babel-polyfill', './index.js'],
    }
}


// index.js
// babel-polyfill import removed
...
```

Which one is preferred, and why?

Answer (score 1):

Both works kind of the same way. 
The option 1, webpack would treat `babel-polyfill` as a dependency, in the dependency tree.

The second one, webpack would treat `babel-polyfill` as an entrypoint, where it would try to generate a dependency graph from that, which would have 0 dependencies.

There is no real difference here, nor any impact on the result bundle, both will contain babel-polyfill anyways, and also there is no "preferred" way to add that, babel itself refeers to both ways on their guide.

Answer (score 0):

The result will be the same. It depends on you, usually I prefer to import the dependencies in modules rather than importing implicitly in webpack config.